# Where do I put item tags on items inside a chest or your inventory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a Minecraft Mini Game adventure map, and one of the levels has a `/setblock` command, I am using the command in a way to spawn an item in a chest (Wooden Button) I need the wooden button to have `CanPlaceOn` tag so it can be placed on a log.

I have tried this command:

```
setblock 294 5 -1251 minecraft:chest 0 replace {Items:[{Count:1,Slot:0,id:minecraft:wooden_button,CanPlaceOn:[log]}]}`
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `CanPlaceOn` list and all other item data is inside the `tag` compound tag:

```
{
  Items:[ 
    {
      id: "minecraft:wooden_button",
      Count: 1b,
      Slot: 0b,
      tag:{
        CanPlaceOn:[
          "minecraft:log"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Example command for 1.12−:

```
/setblock 294 5 -1251 minecraft:chest 0 replace {Items:[{Count:1b,Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:wooden_button",tag:{CanPlaceOn:["log"]}}]}
```

Example command for 1.13+:

```
/setblock 294 5 -1251 minecraft:chest{Items:[{Count:1b,Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:wooden_button",tag:{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:log"]}}]}
```

Item NBT structure can be found on [this wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format#Item_structure).

Common mistakes include:

- forgetting `tag`:

  ```
  {
    id: "minecraft:wooden_button",
    Count: 1b,
    CanPlaceOn: [
      "minecraft:log"
    ]
  }
  ```
- attempting to put it inside the item ID:

  ```
  {
    id: "minecraft:wooden_button{CanPlaceOn:['minecraft:log']}",
    Count: 1b
  }
  ```