# How do I connect my potion-command to my villager's trading-system?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I've got this command:

```
/summon Villager ~1 ~ ~ {
    Profession: 2,
    CustomName: "Aldorf the wizzard",
    CustomNameVisible: 1,
    Career: 1,
    CareerLevel: 42,
    PersistenceRequired: 1,
    Silent: 1,
    Invulnerable: 1,
    Attributes: [
        {
            Name: "generic.maxHealth",
            Base: 99999
        }
    ],
    Offers: {
        Recipes: [
            {
                buy: {
                    id: "record_13",
                    Count: 1
                },
                buyB: {
                    id: "skull",
                    Count: 1,
                    Damage: 1
                },
                maxUses: 9999999,
                sell: {
                    id: "stone",
                    Count: null
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And you can see it says "stone" (null).

Now I want to change it so that I can trade from the disc and the skull (that are already there) into this custom potion:

```
/give @p potion 1 16385 {CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:3,Amplifier:0,Duration:60},{Id:7,Amplifier:0,Duration:60},{Id:9,Amplifier:0,Duration:120},{Id:10,Amplifier:0,Duration:60},{Id:14,Amplifier:0,Duration:20},{Id:15,Amplifier:0,Duration:140},{Id:16,Amplifier:0,Duration:600},{Id:17,Amplifier:500,Duration:600},{Id:18,Amplifier:9,Duration:600},{Id:19,Amplifier:100,Duration:600},{Id:20,Amplifier:100,Duration:200},{Id:23,Amplifier:500,Duration:600}],display:{Name:"Poison",Lore:["Poisons anyone it is used to.","The only way to survive is to drink milk in seconds."]}}
```

How do I connect them? I almost got it but there are these weird "]}}" signs at the end so I couldn't do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do I put item tags on items inside a chest or your inventory?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272179/where-do-i-put-item-tags-on-items-inside-a-chest-or-your-inventory)

Answer (score 1):

Add all of the potion's custom tags to the sell item, inside the `tag` tag:

```
/summon Villager ~1 ~ ~ { Profession: 2, CustomName: "Aldorf the wizzard", CustomNameVisible: 1, Career: 1, CareerLevel: 42, PersistenceRequired: 1, Silent: 1, Invulnerable: 1, Attributes: [ { Name: "generic.maxHealth", Base: 99999 } ], Offers: { Recipes: [ { buy: { id: "record_13", Count: 1 }, buyB: { id: "skull", Count: 1, Damage: 1 }, maxUses: 9999999, sell: { id: "potion", Count: 1, tag: { CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:3,Amplifier:0,Duration:60},{Id:7,Amplifier:0,Duration:60},{Id:9,Amplifier:0,Duration:120},{Id:10,Amplifier:0,Duration:60},{Id:14,Amplifier:0,Duration:20},{Id:15,Amplifier:0,Duration:140},{Id:16,Amplifier:0,Duration:600},{Id:17,Amplifier:500,Duration:600},{Id:18,Amplifier:9,Duration:600},{Id:19,Amplifier:100,Duration:600},{Id:20,Amplifier:100,Duration:200},{Id:23,Amplifier:500,Duration:600}],display:{Name:"Poison",Lore:["Poisons anyone it is used to.","The only way to survive is to drink milk in seconds."]} } } } ] } }
```