# Summoning items with enchantments

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am attempting to modify a `/summon` command to add an enchantment. My command looks like this:

```
summon item 8 62 -13 {Item:{id:minecraft:bow,Count:1}}
```

I have tried modifying the command like this:

```
summon item 8 62 -13 {Item:{id:minecraft:bow,Count:1,ench:[{id:19,lvl:1}]}}
```

But it does not apply any enchantments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command for spawning chest with a CanPlaceOn tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272179/command-for-spawning-chest-with-a-canplaceon-tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the item format, all tags that are not the root `id`, `Damage`, `Count`, and `Slot`, must be placed within a single `tag` compound:

```
/summon minecraft:item 8 62 -13 {Item:{id:"minecraft:bow",Count:1,tag:{ench:[{id:19,lvl:1}]}}}
```