# How can you summon an armor stand with a player skull?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am wondering how to summon an armor stand with a head.

I am making a herobrine summoner with command blocks and need an armor stand with all diamond armor and a skull of herobrine, but this command I am using is not working:

```
/summon minecraft:armor_stand ~ ~1 ~ {ShowArms:1,NoBasePlate:1,ArmorItems:[{Count:1,id:diamond_boots}, {Count:1,id:diamond_leggings},{Count:1,id:diamond_chestplate}, {Count:1,id:skull SkullOwner:herobrine}]}
```

Comment: What version are you in?

Comment: i am in version 1.11.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do I put item tags on items inside a chest or your inventory?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272179/where-do-i-put-item-tags-on-items-inside-a-chest-or-your-inventory)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you need to put the SkullOwner into the `tag` component of the item and not only separate it with a whitespace. Also, you need the `Damaged` tag for it to be a human's head.

```
/summon armor_stand ~ ~1 ~ {ShowArms:1,NoBasePlate:1,ArmorItems:[{id:diamond_boots,Count:1b},{id:diamond_leggings,Count:1b},{id:diamond_chestplate,Count:1b},{id:skull,Damage:3,Count:1b,tag:{SkullOwner:Herobrine}}]}
```

Comment: you seem to be missing the `MHF_` prefix for the Herobrine skull - [source](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Mob_head#Mojang_skins)

Comment: 1. the original request was using `herobrine` and not `MHF_Herobrine`.
2. [Herobrine](https://namemc.com/profile/Herobrine.1) is a valid head as well. It might not be as future-proof as the MHF one, but it is indeed a valid Herobrine head.