# I need help with creating a Shulker Box with enchanted items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

```
/give @p chest 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5,id:diamond_sword,Slot:0,Count:64},{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]}
```

This is a smaller version of the code my goal is to have it give me a shulker box with these enchanted items.

Comment: This is an extremely long command and you probably don't need most of it. Try reducing it to the relevant parts and see if it works.

Comment: Try troubleshooting your command with one item stack first since they're the same items anyway. Copy&Pasting an error 20+ times doesn't make it easier to find and fix it.

Comment: If you want help it would be a good idea to give at least some information about it. What do you want to do, what is wrong with it and some formatting of the code.

Comment: I am trying to give myself a shucker box filled with these enchanted items thats why its so big sorry for the little info on it

Comment: @Don what's the error message you're getting?

Comment: Starting with Minecraft 1.9 any commands using JSON syntax (the stuff in curly brackets) need to actually be compliant with the JSON standard. You can use online JSON validation tools to check. For example, pasting your code into [JSON Formatter & Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) gives the Error message *"Strings should be wrapped in double quotes."*. Basically every bit of text - "BlockEntityTag", "Items" etc etc needs to be in double quotes.

Comment: @Robotnik Minecraft isn't that strict. You can do that for validation purposes, but it should work without all the quotes (with some exceptions and the new rules that came with 1.12).

Comment: @dly [Strict JSON as of 1.9](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/2489331-converting-your-json-data-for-the-1-9-update)

Comment: @Robotnik NBT Tags are not JSON although they look like it. Only tellraw and title commands (and some parts of NBT data, like sign texts) use strict JSON.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do I put item tags on items inside a chest or your inventory?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272179/where-do-i-put-item-tags-on-items-inside-a-chest-or-your-inventory)

Answer (score 5):

**For fixing bugs line breaks are pure win.** It is way easier to read the code and address the actual issues instead of looking through all the gibberish for the needle in a haystack.

Just to have something to look at...

This is your code in a fixed state (removed stuff from old edit and fixed the brackets:

```
/give @p chest 1 0 {
    BlockEntityTag:{
        Items:[
            {
                display:{
                    Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",
                    Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]
                },
                AttributeModifiers:[
                {
                    AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",
                    Name:"generic.maxHealth",
                    Amount:100,
                    Operation:0,
                    UUIDMost:15145,
                    UUIDLeast:331544
                }],
                ench:[
                    {id:0,lvl:1000},
                    {id:1,lvl:1000},
                    {id:2,lvl:1000},
                    {id:3,lvl:1000},
                    {id:4,lvl:1000},
                    {id:5,lvl:1000},
                    {id:6,lvl:1000},
                    {id:7,lvl:1000},
                    {id:8,lvl:1000},
                    {id:16,lvl:1000},
                    {id:17,lvl:1000},
                    {id:18,lvl:1000},
                    {id:19,lvl:1000},
                    {id:20,lvl:1000},
                    {id:21,lvl:10},
                    {id:32,lvl:1000},
                    {id:33,lvl:1000},
                    {id:34,lvl:10000},
                    {id:35,lvl:100},
                    {id:48,lvl:1000},
                    {id:49,lvl:1000},
                    {id:50,lvl:1000},
                    {id:51,lvl:1000},
                    {id:61,lvl:100},
                    {id:62,lvl:100}
                ],
                HideFlags:5,
                id:diamond_sword,
                Slot:0,Count:64
            }]
        }
    }
```

That already looks good and doesn't have any JSON errors. Your syntax is wrong, though. The item's attributes need to be encased in a `tag: { ... }`. This should fix your problem (untested, since I don't have Minecraft here):

```
/give @p chest 1 0 {
    BlockEntityTag:{
        Items:[
            {
                tag:{
                    display:{
                        Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",
                        Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]
                    },
                    AttributeModifiers:[
                    {
                        AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",
                        Name:"generic.maxHealth",
                        Amount:100,
                        Operation:0,
                        UUIDMost:15145,
                        UUIDLeast:331544
                    }],
                    ench:[
                        {id:0,lvl:1000},
                        {id:1,lvl:1000},
                        {id:2,lvl:1000},
                        {id:3,lvl:1000},
                        {id:4,lvl:1000},
                        {id:5,lvl:1000},
                        {id:6,lvl:1000},
                        {id:7,lvl:1000},
                        {id:8,lvl:1000},
                        {id:16,lvl:1000},
                        {id:17,lvl:1000},
                        {id:18,lvl:1000},
                        {id:19,lvl:1000},
                        {id:20,lvl:1000},
                        {id:21,lvl:10},
                        {id:32,lvl:1000},
                        {id:33,lvl:1000},
                        {id:34,lvl:10000},
                        {id:35,lvl:100},
                        {id:48,lvl:1000},
                        {id:49,lvl:1000},
                        {id:50,lvl:1000},
                        {id:51,lvl:1000},
                        {id:61,lvl:100},
                        {id:62,lvl:100}
                    ],
                    HideFlags:5
                },
                id:diamond_sword,
                Slot:0,
                Count:64
            }]
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tested the fixed command.  It does run properly.

Comment: Indentation also helps a lot to read code. What can help too is a software that can color code. Go get sublime text or atom, and put the code in this language (i dont know what itis)

Comment: @Fredy31 it's JSON syntax with a few exceptions. Syntax highlighting should still work, though. I use Eclipse or Notepad++ for this depending on what I'm working on.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the command I came up with.  It gives a black shulker box named 'Shadow Guard Sword' that is filled with stacks of the desired sword.  It is a very long command.

```
/give @p minecraft:black_shulker_box 1 0  {BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:diamond_sword,Slot:0,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:1,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:2,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:3,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:4,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:5,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:6,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:7,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:8,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:9,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:10,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:11,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:12,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:13,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:14,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:14,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:15,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:16,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:17,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:18,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:19,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:20,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:21,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:22,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:23,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:24,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:25,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:26,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}},{id:diamond_sword,Slot:27,Count:64,tag:{display:{Name:"SHADOW_GUARD_SWORD",Lore:["SHADOWS_JUDGMENT!"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:100,Operation:0,UUIDMost:15145,UUIDLeast:331544}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:1000},{id:1,lvl:1000},{id:2,lvl:1000},{id:3,lvl:1000},{id:4,lvl:1000},{id:5,lvl:1000},{id:6,lvl:1000},{id:7,lvl:1000},{id:8,lvl:1000},{id:16,lvl:1000},{id:17,lvl:1000},{id:18,lvl:1000},{id:19,lvl:1000},{id:20,lvl:1000},{id:21,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:33,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:10000},{id:35,lvl:100},{id:48,lvl:1000},{id:49,lvl:1000},{id:50,lvl:1000},{id:51,lvl:1000},{id:61,lvl:100},{id:62,lvl:100}],HideFlags:3}}]},display:{Name:"Shadow Guard Sword"}}
```

[image: Image 1]

---

Edit:  I updated the command to include the requested hideflags.  The command above is now hiding the enchantments and modifiers.

[image: Image 2]

Also, just to note it, you don't need underscores in the name or lore.  This is what it looks like if you don't:

[image: Image 3]

Comment: Can u put a hide flags command on them so they don't show the modifiers etc :P But thank u so much :)))

Comment: The answer now includes the requested hideflags.

Comment: Ur the best dude