# How do I put a custom potion in a shulker box with a command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

This is a command of a working `/give` potion. It places a potion of the desired colour in the inventory.

What I'm having a problem with is when putting it inside a chest that I'm spawning, the command does not work. Can you help me? I am trying to put it inside of a shulker box

```
/give @p minecraft:potion 1 0 {Potion:"minecraft:water",CustomPotionColor:16777215,CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:9,Duration:100}],display:{Name:"Custom Name"}}]}}
```

Comment: What ARE you trying to do? All I see it a command. Either it does what you want to do or it doesn't. But if you don't understand what you want to do, I can't know if the command does it or not. And what exactly is your problem?

Comment: @fabian I have edited it to explain better

Comment: @GamerGirl1 For a next question, please keep in mind that other people need to read your question too. Please apply basic grammar to posts (aka a sentence starts with a capital letter and ends with a dot).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do I put item tags on items inside a chest or your inventory?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272179/where-do-i-put-item-tags-on-items-inside-a-chest-or-your-inventory)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after several hours of headache! Here is the solution:

```
/give @p minecraft:black_shulker_box 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:black_shulker_box,Slot:0,Count:64,tag:{BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{id:stone,Slot:0,Count:64},{id:splash_potion,tag:{Potion:"minecraft:water",CustomPotionColor:16777215,CustomPotionEffects: [{Id: 2,Amplifier: 100,Duration: 199999980}, {Id: 14,Amplifier: 1,Duration: 1999980}],display: {Name: "Glitch"}},Slot:1,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:2,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:3,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:4,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:5,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:6,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:7,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:8,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:9,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:10,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:11,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:12,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:13,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:14,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:15,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:16,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:17,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:18,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:19,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:20,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:21,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:22,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:23,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:24,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:25,Count:64},{id:stone,Slot:26,Count:64}]}}}
```

I wanted to change the color id of a potion from pink to black or white and I put this in after the tag: bracket `{Potion:"minecraft:water",CustomPotionColor:16777215,` and it came out how I wanted it.

Comment: Please mark your own answer as accepted so that this question doesn't remain open.

Comment: @Fabian - As the question OP they cannot do so for 2 days.

Comment: @GamerGirl1 can you explain what the problem was and what you did to fix it?

Comment: @Robotnik I wanted to change the color id of a potion from pink to black or white and if I remember correctly I put this in after the tag: bracket {Potion:"minecraft:water",CustomPotionColor:16777215, and it came out how I wanted it :)

Comment: The command in the answer will not run.  You have to add `]}}` to the end of it in order for it to run successfully.

Comment: Please mark your own answer as accepted so that this question doesn't remain open.