# How does one put player skulls into a Shulker box?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How does one put player skulls into a shucker box here is what I have got:

```
/give @p chest 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{Slot:0,id:skull,tag:{SkullOwner:"MHF_Enderman”},Count:64}]}}
```

```
/give @p skull 1 3 {SkullOwner:"MHF_Enderman"}
```

Comment: take a look at this question: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/316592/how-do-i-put-a-custom-potion-in-a-shulker-box-with-a-command-block

Comment: @DLaverick That is another of my questions and no it does not fix the issue here

Answer (score 2):

You're forgetting `Damage:3s` to indicate it's a player skull.

```
/give @p minecraft:black_shulker_box 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{Slot:0b,id:"minecraft:skull",Damage:3s,Count:64b,tag:{SkullOwner:"MHF_Enderman"}}]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.
I might be wrong.
/give @p minecraft:purple_shulker_box 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{Slot:0,id:"minecraft:skull",Damage:3,Count:64b,tag:{SkullOwner:{Name:"dlav"}}}]}}

This should give you my head 64 times in slot 0 of the purple SB. I think... ;)
Just replace the skull owner part and you're good to go.

Comment: just as I was posting... some one beat me to it lol