# Need help with custom villager trading

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Ok, I've been using a command block to spawn a villager that has custom trades. There's no problem with that at all- I'm just wondering if it's possible to have a villager trade me an item that has a custom name (eg. Key). Or is this unchangeable, so I'd need to name it with an anvil after purchase?

```
/summon Villager ~ ~1 ~ {Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:"minecraft:emerald",Count:4},sell:{id:"minecraft:leather_helmet",Count:1}},{buy:{id:"minecraft:emerald",Count:6},sell:{id:"minecraft:leather_chestplate",Count:1}},{buy:{id:"minecraft:emerald",Count:5},sell:{id:"minecraft:leather_leggings",Count:1}}]}}
```

The code is fully functional, it's just integrating custom names for the item he sells.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command for spawning chest with a CanPlaceOn tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272179/command-for-spawning-chest-with-a-canplaceon-tag)

Answer (score 2):

NBT you would include in /give commands for items goes inside the "tag" compound. https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format#Item_structure

```
/summon Villager ~ ~1 ~ {Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:"minecraft:emerald",Count:4b},sell:{id:"minecraft:leather_helmet",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"Foo"}}}},{buy:{id:"minecraft:emerald",Count:6b},sell:{id:"minecraft:leather_chestplate",Count:1b}},{buy:{id:"minecraft:emerald",Count:5b},sell:{id:"minecraft:leather_leggings",Count:1b}}]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are wanting to add data that would require adding a [data tag](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Data_tags).  Lets look at the first item sold:

```
sell:{id:"minecraft:leather_chestplate",Count:1}
```

The [give command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#give) to give this item is:

```
/give @p minecraft:leather_chestplate 1
```

To add a name to the give command, the dataTag argument needs to be specified:

```
/give @p minecraft:leather_chestplate 1 0 {display:{Name:"The custom name"}}
```

In your command, everything contained within the `sell` compound is defining the item.  This requires following the [item structure](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format#Item_structure), which means the data tag information has to be within a `tag` compound:

```
tag:{display:{Name:"The custom name"}}
```

This would give you a final sell compound of:

```
sell:{id:"minecraft:leather_chestplate",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:"The custom name"}}}
```

You can add the tag compound to any of the `buy` or `sell` compounds in your summon command.

You can also specify enchantments, attribute modifiers, flags, lore, etc. within the tag compound.