# How to use datatags in trades?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making an adventure map and I need to make villagers who do not take damage and trade items with the `CanDestroy` and `CanPlaceOn` tags. How can I do that? All of my command generators don't allow data tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command for spawning chest with a CanPlaceOn tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272179/command-for-spawning-chest-with-a-canplaceon-tag)

Answer (score 1):

You can put a `tag`-tag into the `sell`-tag of the trade. Your command may look like this:

```
/summon minecraft:villager <coordinates> {
  Invulnerable:1b,
  PersistenceRequired:1b,
  Offers:
  {
    Recipes:
    [
      {
        maxUses:8,
        buy:{id:"minecraft:emerald",Count: 1b},
        buyB:{id:"minecraft:air",Count:1b},
        sell:{
          tag: {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:stone","minecraft:iron_ore"]},
          id:"minecraft:stone",
          Count: 1b}
      },
      {
        maxUses:8,
        buy:{id:"minecraft:emerald",Count: 1b},
        buyB:{id:"minecraft:air",Count: 1b},
        sell:{
          tag:{CanDestroy:["minecraft:stone","minecraft:iron_ore"]},
          id:"minecraft:diamond_pickaxe",
          Count: 1b
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The `Invulnerable`-tag makes the villager invulnerable, the only way to hurt/kill it is by a player in creative mode, or if it falls out of the world into the void.

The `PersistenceRequired`-tag prevents the villager from despawning, I´m not sure if that is nessessary though.

In the `Offers`-tag, you have the `maxUses`-tag, which defines how often you can trade a certain offer, before the villager has to stock up
`buy` and `buyB` tags are the items that the villager buys from you
`sell` is the items that the villager sells to you. To add a `CanDestroy`, or `CanPlaceOn` to the item, you use the `tag`-tag.

From the villager from the example you can get stone that you can place on other stone blocks, or on iron ore, and a diamond pickaxe that you can use to break stone, and iron ore.

*Note: The villager will have different trades after it changes profession*

Answer (score 0):

On the item, where, presumably, you wrote `id:minecraft:sword` (for example), say `, tags:{` and write your tags there.

Hope this works!