# How can I convert my custom give command to a Minecraft villager trade command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I just made a command for an invisibility potion that lasts 25 seconds. (3 min is way to long for the mini-game I am making.) Here is the code:

```
/give @p minecraft:potion{CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:14,Duration:500,ShowParticles:0b}],CustomPotionColor:16576248,display:{Name:"\"Potion of Invisibility\""}}
```

I just don't know how to turn it into put it into this villager trade command:

```
{buy:{id:emerald,Count:2},sell:{id:potion,Count:1,tag:{Potion:"minecraft:invisibility"}}}]}}\
```

It would be in place of the sell portion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command for spawning chest with a CanPlaceOn tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272179/command-for-spawning-chest-with-a-canplaceon-tag)

Answer (score 2):

The `tag` tag contains all the NBT tags of the item, so you simply put `CustomPotionEffects`, `CustomPotionColor` and `display` into there.

Comment: okay ill try it!

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work any tips @Fabian? ```{buy:{id:emerald,Count:2},sell:{id:potion,Count:1,tag:{minecraft:{CustomPotionEffects:[{Id:14,Duration:500,ShowParticles:0b}],CustomPotionColor:16576248,display:{Name:"\"Potion of Invisibility\""}}}} ```

Comment: @tanner The `minecraft:` part does not belong.