# How do I add a CanDestroy tag into an iron pickaxe that I'm placing on a dispenser?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So basically, I'm trying to make a puzzle map with custom recipes, and I'm trying to make it so when you place a stone pickaxe in the middle of a dispenser, and 3 iron ingots on top of it, it gives you an iron pickaxe that can only destroy concrete.
I've been trying a lot of stuff but I don't get how I am gonna get it to work.
This is the command I'm using for this.

```
/blockdata 11 4 3 {CustomName:"Fabricación",Items:[{Slot:4b,id:"minecraft:iron_pickaxe",Count:1b,Damage:0s}],CanDestroy:"minecraft:concrete",id:"minecraft:dispenser",Lock:""}
```

Also, im on 1.12.2

Comment: `/blockdata` has been removed in 2018. I haven't checked the rest, but you have `CanDestroy` and `id:"dispenser"` on the same level, that definitely can't be right.

Comment: Perhaps because im on 1.12.2 i guess i forgot to say that.. Oops?

Comment: Alright, then the second problem that I mentioned. Put `CanDestroy` into a to-be-created "`tag`" tag of the item instead of the root tag of the dispenser. Also, I recommend looking at old pages of the wiki for things like this: [commands](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/index.php?title=Commands&oldid=1161920), [NBT](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/index.php?title=Chunk_format&oldid=1159744)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command for spawning chest with a CanPlaceOn tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272179/command-for-spawning-chest-with-a-canplaceon-tag)