# Villager trade issue with canplaceon item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have this command:

```
/summon villager -179 64 95 {VillagerData:{profession:farmer,level:2,type:plains},Invulnerable:1,NoAI:1,CustomName:"\"Gardener\"",Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:wheat_seeds,Count:3,CanPlaceOn:["farmland"]},rewardExp:0b,maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:wheat,Count:1},sell:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},rewardExp:0b,maxUses:9999999}]}}
```

Formatted:

```
/summon villager -179 64 95 {
  VillagerData { 
    profession:farmer,
    level:2,
    type:plains
  },
  Invulnerable:1,
  NoAI:1,
  CustomName:"\"Gardener\"",
  Offers:{
    Recipes:[{
      buy:{
        id:gold_nugget,
        Count:3
      },
      sell:{
        id:wheat_seeds,
        Count:3,
        CanPlaceOn:["farmland"]
      },
      rewardExp:0b,
      maxUses:9999999
    },{
      buy:{
        id:wheat,
        Count:1
      },
      sell:{
        id:gold_nugget,
        Count:3
      },
      rewardExp:0b,
      maxUses:9999999
    }]
  }
}
```

It works pretty well, but these seeds being sold cannot be placed on farmland. anybody understand why it doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `"farmland"` with `"minecraft:farmland"`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do I put item tags on items inside a chest or your inventory?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272179/where-do-i-put-item-tags-on-items-inside-a-chest-or-your-inventory)