# Issue with a CanPlaceOn object for trade

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have this command

`/summon villager -179 64 95 {VillagerData:{profession:farmer,level:2,type:plains},Invulnerable:1,NoAI:1,CustomName:"\"Gardener\"",Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:wheat_seeds,Count:3,CanPlaceOn:["farmland"]},rewardExp:0b,maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:wheat,Count:1},sell:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},rewardExp:0b,maxUses:9999999}]}}`

it works well, but in line 3-4 those wheat seeds are not place able on farmland. I checked around this website for an answer but no real answers. anybody know what I did?

Comment: "This user likes to keep an air of mystery" is what's displayed on your profile page when you haven't filled in any personal details, not on a question page. I'm submitting an edit to remove that part, since it isn't relevant to your actual question.

Comment: @tripleee done, thanks for telling me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do I put item tags on items inside a chest or your inventory?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272179/where-do-i-put-item-tags-on-items-inside-a-chest-or-your-inventory)

Answer (score 0):

Item properties (such as **CanPlaceOn**) should be specified in the **tag** tag.

```
/summon villager -179 64 95 {VillagerData:{profession:farmer,level:2,type:plains},Invulnerable:1,NoAI:1,CustomName:"\"Gardener\"",Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},sell:{id:wheat_seeds,Count:3,tag:{CanPlaceOn:["farmland"]}},rewardExp:0b,maxUses:9999999},{buy:{id:wheat,Count:1},sell:{id:gold_nugget,Count:3},rewardExp:0b,maxUses:9999999}]}}
```

There is lots of information about the structure of item NBT data on the wiki: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format#Item_structure

Comment: that specific code doesn't work, but thanks for the info

Edit: it does work, my bad. thank you so much!

Comment: @DamseyDoo please mark the answer as accepted if it answers your question :)