# How do I summon an item with a custom name?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to summon a potion item with a custom name. I did use

```
/summon minecraft:item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:potion",Count:1b},display:{Name:'{"text":"Teleporter","italic":"false"}'},PickupDelay:8}
```

But it doesn't have the name I want. It has the normal uncraftable potion name.

Does anyone know how to fix it? I'm on Java 1.18.1.

Comment: Are you trying to let the item entity display custom name or do you want to get yourself a potion item with a custom name?

Comment: I'm trying to summon an item with custom name.

Comment: You should be using `/give` for items instead of `/summon`, which is for entities.

Comment: I know how to use `/give` for it but I want when there are 2 specific items on the ground 
 they turn into a custom levitation splash potion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do I put item tags on items inside a chest or your inventory?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272179/where-do-i-put-item-tags-on-items-inside-a-chest-or-your-inventory) (and for what it's worth I don't think this is unclear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `display` key has to be under both the `Item` key and another key called `tag`. The full command would look like this:

```
/summon minecraft:item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:potion",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:'{"text":"Teleporter","italic":"false"}'}}},PickupDelay:8}
```

The minecraft wiki has information on the entity data structure of items [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Entity_format#Items_and_XP_Orbs).