# How do I /give an item with 1 durability and can only break certain blocks like dirt in 1.18.1

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have tried the following:

```
/give @p minecraft:diamond_pickaxe{Damage:1560{CanDestroy:["minecraft:dirt"]}} 1
```

However, this doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by “doesn’t work”?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do I put item tags on items inside a chest or your inventory?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272179/where-do-i-put-item-tags-on-items-inside-a-chest-or-your-inventory)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your error (errors are in **bold**):
/give @p minecraft:diamond_pickaxe{Damage:1560 **{** CanDestroy:["minecraft:dirt"] **}** } 1

Remove the **bolded** text and add a comma before "CanDestroy"

Like this:
/give @a minecraft:diamond_pickaxe{Damage:1560,CanDestroy:["minecraft:dirt"]} 1

You can also make it mine more than dirt with this:
/give @a minecraft:diamond_pickaxe{Damage:1560,CanDestroy:["minecraft:dirt","minecraft:stone"]} 1

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).