# How do I summon an enchanted item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I tried this command:

```
/summon item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:iron_pickaxe,Count:1,Enchantments:{id:fortune,lvl:1}}}
```

But the Iron pickaxe was without enchantment.

I'm on Minecraft java 1.18.1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do I put item tags on items inside a chest or your inventory?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272179/where-do-i-put-item-tags-on-items-inside-a-chest-or-your-inventory)

Comment: @pinckerman Not a duplicate of your linked question because they have the enchantment syntax correct and the actual problem is with higher-level item syntax.

Comment: @pppery sorry, I knew it was a dupe but I couldn't find the correct one

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try:

```
/summon item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:iron_pickaxe",Count:1b,tag:{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:fortune",lvl:1s}]}}}
```

The changes:[image]

I used MC stacker at https://mcstacker.net/
Mc stacker can help you create commands easily.
[image]

I tested this and it works!