# Trying to summon an dropped diamond with a name and enchantment; only summons dropped diamond

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

```
/summon minecraft:item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:diamond",CustomModelData:775000,display:{Name:'[{"text":"Enchanted Diamond","italic":false}]'},Enchantments:[{id:mending,lvl:1}],HideFlags:1,Count:1b}}
```

It's supposed to summon a dropped item named "enchanted diamond" with a mending enchantment, but it just summons a dropped diamond.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! On Minecraft commands questions, please see our [guide on what to do before asking a Minecraft commands question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13507/4797), especially the part about “what you’ve tried so far”, and [edit] in the requested information to your post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do I put item tags on items inside a chest or your inventory?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272179/where-do-i-put-item-tags-on-items-inside-a-chest-or-your-inventory)

Answer (score -1):

For things like this I suggest using the wonderful website [mcstacker.net](https://www.mcstacker.net)
I'm going to assume you don't actually need the enchantment to work and just want the enchantment glint, as mending does not work on diamonds.

This command is probably what you are looking for:

```
/summon item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:diamond",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:'{"text":"Enchanted Diamond","italic":false}'},CustomModelData:775000,Enchantments:[{}]}}}
```

Anyone else is probably using a different CustomModelData value or none at all, so here is a general purpose command for anyone else who might need this:

```
/summon item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:diamond",Count:1b,tag:{display:{Name:'{"text":"Enchanted Diamond","italic":false}'},Enchantments:[{}]}}}
```